# want to take several rects from a png and save them as seperate png files. c++

Tags: c++, png, sdl-2

I'm making a c++ console program. I have a 1920x1080 png. i want to take several rects from it (1701, 160 to 1720, 177 as an example of one rectangle) then I want to save each as it's own png file. they are then going to be fed into an ocr program so it would help if i could at the same time sharply resize them up by a factor of 10x but if not i can do that with a separate console app (without this step the OCR program produces random noise).

first i was trying to use .net 4.5 but microsoft's code samples were unintelligible for me.

now I'm thinking that maybe SDL2 might be able to do this easily for me?

Whats the simplest easiest cross platform way to do this.

I'm using visual studio 2013 on windows 8.1

Comment: As far as I know, `SDL_image` can't save image files

Comment: @Aaron - Windows and *nix?

Comment: yes I'd like windows and *nix support

Comment: @MarkSetchell it looks like imagemagic is going to work for me

convert input.png -crop 220x17+1481+160 1.png
    convert input.png -crop 220x17+1481+179 2.png

etc

Comment: Excellent! It's a great tool to have in your toolbox.